# How to format time with decimal places with excel vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to write a macro that takes a time value in seconds (decimal) and converts it to mm:ss.00 format (two decimal places.) The closest I've come is this:

```
Application.Text((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")
```

Which results in:

```
00:01.2
```

I can't figure out why it's not showing the second decimal place. Format() doesn't work either, it does something even weirder.

Comment: This is strange - on my machine your returned the expected `00:01.23`. Could it be locale specific?

Comment: Mine has the same result as Peter Albert. I used the immediate window for `Debug.Print Application.Text((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")` and the result was `00:01.23`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [.numberformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224873%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property?

e.g.

```
Cells(2, 3) = Application.Text((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")
Cells(2, 3).NumberFormat = "mm:ss.00"
```